# Windows 10 XAMPP - PDO connection fine, cannot connect via mysqli or mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using a Windows 10 PC which has XAMPP installed (v3.2.2).

If I do this in MySQL:

```
select version();
-- 10.1.32-MariaDB
```

That confirms the version...

I have a test database called "wp", and the username and password are both set to "wp".

I can connect to the database without a problem using PDO, but I can't connect using mysqli or mysqli_connect, and I can't see why. I've wasted a few hours on this today so far. I'm trying to install Wordpress on XAMPP but the installer says it can't connect to the database, so I have been testing around this, hence this question.

## mysqli

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "wp";
$password = "wp";
$dbname = "wp";
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'wp'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\public_html\_conn.php on line 6
```

## mysqli_connect

```
$host = "localhost";
$uname = "wp";
$pwd = "wp";
$dbname = "wp";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $uname, $pwd, $dbname);

// Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'wp'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\public_html\_conn.php on line 13
```

## pdo

```
$config['db'] = array(
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'username'  => 'wp',
    'password'  => 'wp',
    'dbname'    => 'wp'
);

try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' .$config['db']['host']. ';port=33066;dbname=' .$config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING, true);
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// connects fine
```

The `wp` user has the correct level of access:

[image]

Since the same user details are used to connect via PDO, but they don't work for the other methods.

I have checked using `phpinfo();` and can see that `mysqli` is set up as far as I can see (I searched for `mysqli_connect` but can't see it listed):

## mysqli phpinfo

[image]

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//This line of code connects to mysql database
define("HOST_NAME", "localhost:3306");
define("HOST_USER", "wp");
define("HOST_PASS", "wp");
define("HOST_DB", "wp");

$db = new mysqli(HOST_NAME, HOST_USER, HOST_PASS, HOST_DB);


 // This line of code checks if connection error exists.

if($db->connect_error) {
    echo $db->connect_errno . " " . $db->connect_error;
} else {
    echo "Connection successful.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get this response: `Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'wp'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\public_html\_conn.php on line 50` where line 50 = `$db = new mysqli(HOST_NAME, HOST_USER, HOST_PASS, HOST_DB);`

Comment: But why would the password be okay for PDO, but not for the other methods of connecting? I changed the pwd to `becausethis1` and still, nothing connects except PDO.

Comment: Ok. But apart from the WordPress, does connection establishes without problems with mysqli? Try and create a new database and create a script to connect, if it does, then you'll have to concentrate on the WordPress

Comment: No - it doesn't work with the simple _conn.php file I have created whose contents I quoted in the question. I can't connect using mysqli. I'll try to uninstall and reinstall XAMPP in case that does the trick.

Comment: Try username: root and a blank password